# Scheduler to create and delete container instances

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-registry

Is it possible to create a schedule that will automatically create an instance of the container and delete it at the specified time?
For example, at 8 am, creates a container instance from a container register and will delete it by 4 pm?
I tried azure automation but I did not find the right option.

Comment: Try to use the runbook and link to the schedule.

Comment: Try to use [Jenkins with ACI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-jenkins).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in many ways

1. Write small Azure function with HTTP trigger and configure Azure Scheduler in portal which will trigger Azure function at specified time and maybe another schedule to stop those VM

[image]

2. 2 Time triggered Azure functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure ARM APIs to achieve this. Write a small program on Azure Function and try this,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-service/containerservices

Azure Function,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set a azure schedule and connect it to the runbooks.
Runbooks with a PS script with the AzureRM.ContainerInstance module.